# How to read new version of iwork files like .numbers, .key, .pages

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, apache-tika

I have multiple mac files like .numbers, .key, .pages i want to read it. i tried it with Tika library

**org.apache.tika.parser.iwork.IWorkPackageParser**

but it support only previous version of mac files, it can't read iwa formatted mac files. anyone have idea about this ?

Comment: See [TIKA-1358](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1358) for the Apache Tika work so far on adding support, but there's still a lot of work to do. See [obriensp](https://github.com/obriensp/iWorkFileFormat) for some info on the file format. [This project](https://github.com/ChloeTigre/pyiwa) might help you a bit...